# Negative indexing in Python

Tags: python, list

I have one record in a list

```
>>> bob =['bob smith',42,30000,'software']
```

I am trying to get the last name 'smith' from this record

I use the below command:

```
>>> bob[0].split()[1]
```

It provides me 'smith'

But the book I am referring to use the below command:

```
>>> bob[0].split()[-1]
```

it also gives me same result 'smith'

Why do indexes [1] and [-1] provide the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python lists can be "back indexed" using negative indices. `-1` signifies the last element, `-2` signifies the second to last and so on. It just so happens that in your list of length 2, the last element is also the element at index `1`.

Your book suggests using `-1` because it is more appropriate from a logical standpoint. You don't want the *item at index `1`* per se, but rather the *last element* of the list, which is the last name. What if, for example, a middle name was also included? Then using an index of `1` would not work whereas an index of `-1` would.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief using -1 for last name is not logical, it isn't even correct (http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Positive indexes count from the start of the list, negative indexes count from the end of the list.

That is:

```
bob[0].split()[0] == 'bob'
bob[0].split()[1] == 'smith'
bob[0].split()[-1] == 'smith'
bob[0].split()[-2] == 'bob'
```

Now say you have someone with a middle name:

```
jane =['jane elizabeth smith', 42, 30000, 'software']
```

`jane[0].split()[1]` would give Jane's middle name `'elizabeth'`, while `jane[0].split()[-1]` would give her last name `'smith'`

Now having said all this;

- do *not* assume a name is made up of two components
- do *not* assume a name is of the form <first name> <last name>
- do *not* assume a first name is one word
- do *not* assume a last name is one word
- do *not* assume anything!!!

For a more exhaustive list of things you might be wrong about see [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Because in this case the list you are splitting is `['adam', 'smith']`. So, `bob[0].split()[1]` would return the 2nd element (don't forget list indexes are 0-based) and `bob[0].split()[-1]` would return that last element.

Since the size of the list is 2, the second (index `1`) and last (index `-1`) are the same.

In general if you have a list `my_list`, then `my_list[len(my_list) - 1] == my_list[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

this is your input

```
In [73]: bob
Out[73]: ['bob smith', 42, 30000, 'software']
```

this is what bob[0] gives you

```
In [74]: bob[0]
Out[74]: 'bob smith'
```

as you can see bob[0] has only two elements so 1 give you second element and -1 gives you last element which is same